# Finding data about Collection in Object SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, user-defined-types

I have Object table COMPANIES with a collection of Employees. The code you can see below.

1. What is a query to find the company with the largest number of employees?
2. How much there are employees with a salary of > 700 in a company 'Company 1'?
3. Show data for Company which has 3 employees.

For this Questions I need 3 SQL queries.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EMPLOYEE_T as OBJECT(
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
    SALARY NUMBER
);


Type EMPLOYEE_T compiled

create or replace type EMPLOYEES_T as table of EMPLOYEE_T;

Type EMPLOYEES_T compiled

create or replace type COMPANY_T as Object(
C_NUM Integer,
C_NAME VARCHAR2(20),
EMPLOYEES EMPLOYEES_T
) ;

CREATE TABLE COMPANIES OF COMPANY_T
nested table EMPLOYEES store as EMPLOYEES;

Table COMPANIES created.

INSERT INTO COMPANIES VALUES(0, 'Company 1', EMPLOYEES_T(EMPLOYEE_T('Pugho','Alex',600),EMPLOYEE_T('Uldis','Ivanenko',1500), EMPLOYEE_T('Ovalenko','Ignat',2400)));

1 row inserted.

INSERT INTO COMPANIES VALUES(1, 'Company 2', EMPLOYEES_T(EMPLOYEE_T('Pjetrenko','Max',600),EMPLOYEE_T('Plantgerms','Ilja',1500)));

1 row inserted.

SELECT * FROM COMPANIES;

     C_NUM C_NAME
---------- --------------------
EMPLOYEES(LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, SALARY)                                                                          1 Company 2            
EMPLOYEES_T(EMPLOYEE_T('Pjetrenko', 'Max', 600), EMPLOYEE_T('Plantgerms', 'Ilja', 1500))                                                
         0 Company 1            
EMPLOYEES_T(EMPLOYEE_T('Pugho', 'Alex', 600), EMPLOYEE_T('Uldis', 'Ivanenko', 1500), EMPLOYEE_T('Ovalenko', 'Ignat', 2400))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this Answer I need 3 votes (if it is correct) :)

**What is a query to find the company with the largest number of employees?**

```
select C_NAME, cnt from (                   
select t1.C_NAME, count(*) as cnt
from companies t1, table(t1.EMPLOYEES)
group by t1.C_NAME)
where cnt = (select max(cnt) from(select t1.C_NAME, count(*) as cnt
                                  from companies t1, table(t1.EMPLOYEES)
                                  group by t1.C_NAME))
```

**How much there are employees with a salary of > 700 in a company 'Company 1'?**

```
select t1.C_NAME, count(*) as cnt
from companies t1, table(t1.EMPLOYEES) t2
where t2.SALARY > 700
and t1.c_name = 'Company 1'
group by t1.C_NAME;
```

**Show data for Company which has 3 employees.**

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from companies t1, table(t1.EMPLOYEES) t2
where t1.C_NAME in (
select t1.C_NAME
from companies t1, table(t1.EMPLOYEES) t2
having count(*) = 3
group by t1.C_NAME);
```